# Is there a word or phrase used to describe a place that you spend lots of time in or you're overly used to?

Tags: word-choice

It could also be an idiom or reference to something as well, that would work. I'm currently using "bedroom" as this, which seems to work, but I'd appreciate a better word for this.

Comment: This is overly general. What is overly used to? Sounds like a place you don't want to be.

Comment: Haunt? Stamping ground?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the context and intention, you could refer to it as your [**den**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/den).